# Formatting inside concat functiion mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to format data inside concat() in mysql. But mysql is prohibiting me when I try doing it. Here's the function :

```
SELECT user_id as id, DATE(leave_from) as date_from, DATE(leave_to) as date_to, NULL as delayed_checkin_remarks, NULL as early_checkout_remarks,  
        CONCAT(
        (' LeaveType : ',
        SELECT title FROM leave_type
        WHERE id = l.leave_type_id),':<br/>',leave_description) 
        as leave_remarks, leave_status
    FROM users_leave_request l 
    WHERE DATE(leave_from) between '2015-01-26' AND '2015-01-30'
```

The problem is when I put that 'LeaveType :' before SELECT inside CONCAT.. otherwise it is working fine. How do I correct it?

Comment: If you want to concat them use quotes around your Select Statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's missplaced parenthesis in your query afer `CONCAT(`

This is better :

```
SELECT user_id as id, DATE(leave_from) as date_from, DATE(leave_to) as date_to, NULL as delayed_checkin_remarks, NULL as early_checkout_remarks,  
        CONCAT(
        ' LeaveType : ',
        (SELECT title FROM leave_type
        WHERE id = l.leave_type_id),':<br/>',leave_description) 
        as leave_remarks, leave_status
    FROM users_leave_request l 
    WHERE DATE(leave_from) between '2015-01-26' AND '2015-01-30'
```

But instead of doing a nested query to get the leave_type description, do a JOIN on the leave_type table in your main query :

```
SELECT l.user_id as id, DATE(l.leave_from) as date_from, DATE(l.leave_to) as l.date_to, NULL as delayed_checkin_remarks, NULL as early_checkout_remarks,  
        CONCAT(' LeaveType : ', lt.title,':<br/>',l.leave_description) AS leave_remarks, 
        l.leave_status
FROM users_leave_request l              
INNER JOIN leave_type lt ON lt.id=l.l.leave_type_id         
WHERE DATE(l.leave_from) between '2015-01-26' AND '2015-01-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use quotes around your Select statement also. Something like this -

```
SELECT user_id as id, DATE(leave_from) as date_from, DATE(leave_to) as date_to, NULL as delayed_checkin_remarks, NULL as early_checkout_remarks,  
    CONCAT(
    (' LeaveType : ',
    'SELECT title FROM leave_type
    WHERE id = l.leave_type_id)',':<br/>',leave_description) 
    as leave_remarks, leave_status
FROM users_leave_request l 
WHERE DATE(leave_from) between '2015-01-26' AND '2015-01-30'
```

Comment: I dont really see how this solves anything. The aim in the CONCAT isn't to print an SQL instruction but to retrieve the leave_type title from another table.